# Apache NiFi write to encrypted SQS queue

Tags: encryption, amazon-sqs, apache-nifi

We are encountering a very strange condition with Apache NiFi and SQS.  We are using the AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService to manage our authentication. If we use an unencrypted queue it works fine, however, if using an encrypted queue it doesn't fail but nothing gets written. It doesn't appear to be generating anything in the NiFi or cloud trail logs either. Just wondered if there is anything special that needs to get done to support this condition. If it is failing, we are not able to figure out where that is occurring. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you please enable more verbose logging by editing `$NIFI_HOME/conf/logback.xml` and adding this line?

`<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.sqs" level="INFO"/>`

After a 30 second refresh, that will put more log output from the SQS processors into your `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file. This may help diagnose. You may also have better luck using remote debugging and putting breakpoints in the `PutSQS.java` processor.

Comment: Thanks Andy! Yep, we will do that and see what we get. Really appreciate the response.

Comment: In your queue's SSE settings, are you using the default KMS Customer Master Key ("aws/sqs") or your own key?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the silent failure with PutSQS under the following conditions:

- SQS Queue configured with server-side encryption using a custom KMS customer master key rather than the default AWS key
- AWS credentials used by NiFi had permission to send a message, but not permissions to use the custom KMS key

The solution was to provide NiFi's AWS credential with the permissions to use both SQS and KMS.  I found the example policy below documented in [What AWS KMS Permissions Do I Need to Use SSE for Amazon SQS?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-server-side-encryption.html#sqs-what-permissions-for-sse):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [{
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "kms:GenerateDataKey",
            "kms:Decrypt"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:123456789012:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"
         }, {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "sqs:SendMessage",
            "sqs:SendMessageBatch"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:123456789012:MyQueue"
      }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @James greatly appreciate it! We will take a look.

Comment: I would assume this would mean that if we have a cluster, we would need to each instance based on their instance ID? We are just trying to figure out how to make sure it isn't brittle if we need to add a node and/or update the hardware. Thanks again!

Comment: The permission change applies to the AWS credential, not directly to the NiFi node(s).  I updated the answer to clarify that.  In my experiment, I used the EC2 instance role, but that is not important to the fix.  If you are using the same credential across cluster nodes, the change would apply to all of them.